# Unable to download images with a space in the URL with cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have the following code for downloading images from remote URL's - the code seems to work ok except where there is a space in the URL - i've put in the str_replace to try to fix this but the problem persists - can anyone suggest what i'm doing wrong when they download they appear as 0kb files.

```
    $image_url = str_replace(" ", "%20", $image_url);
    $fp = fopen($source_image, "wb");
    $ch = curl_init($image_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: can you try with urlencode? you might also need to use CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION

Comment: i'll try the FOLLOWLOCATION -  how do I use the urlencode - is that just wrapped around the whole $image_url variable?

Comment: yeah, don't use str_replace for now - urlencode should take care of it

Comment: Doesn't seem to work - seem to need to do this on part of URL after domain from the looks of it..

Comment: Use rawurlencode rather than urlencode. The latter will put + in place of spaces rather than %20 which the former will do.

Comment: Also, can you try doing wget on the same url that's not working?

Comment: This is the URL i'm trying to download - will give the rawurlencode a try
https://www.kiwigadgets.com/images/LG G2x P999.jpg

Comment: What is the easiest way to run the rawurlencode() on the URL string that comes after the domain? Running it on the whole URL messes up the http bit

Comment: Ok.. i think I need to use parse_url here :)

Comment: Ok.. weird I have another image on the same domain that I can retrieve with spaces.. so the spaces isn't the problem but the fact that one URL has a https rather than the standard http.. do i need an extra setting to deal with https requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sussed it - the site uses https on the images (god knows why) the following worked..

```
    $fp = fopen($source_image, "wb");
    $ch = curl_init($image_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
```